# Either .js or .php file is not running unless page link ends with .html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently creating a website where we take the data of our most visited articles of our website and list them on a specific page.

Now, the way I am collecting the data is by using PHP and I am using JS to generate the result on my page. The thing is that the coding is working but it only works if the page link ends with .html (i.e. www.website.com/article.html) but it my page link is addressed like this: www.website.com/article, the results don't show.

I tried extending the link of my js (i.e. ../result.js) but that doesn't do anything.

If you could please help me figure this out, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!
Here is a sample of the js code:

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function mostVisitedExt()
{
loadXMLDoc('mostvisited.txt',function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
    var res = txt.split('*&^');

document.getElementById("mostVisitedExt").innerHTML =
"<ul class='jrecent'><div class='jname'><p class='body'>"+res[0]+"</p>      </div><div class='jcontent'><a href=http://"+res[0].toLowerCase()+".website.com"+res[20]+" class='body-link' target='_blank'>"+res[10].substring(2, res[10].length-2)+"</a><p class='body'>" + 
res[21] + "</p></div></ul>" +
```

The mostVisitedExt function is the PHP file where it is getting the data from.

Comment: Please provide more information, like what the result.js is doing and how it's interacting with the PHP script.

Comment: I have uploaded the js code. I hope this helps!

Comment: Is "article.html" real file?

Comment: Yes it is a real file! You can view it here: www.avestia.com/recent.html. But if you view it as www.avestia.com/recent, the list on the right does not appear.